# Has there ever been any competitive markup language to X/HTML?

Tags: html, xhtml, markup

This is a question I was wondering about for some time now, but couldn't quite find what I looked for on google.

What I'm wondering is, has there been any competitive markup language to X/HTML, that was essentially supposed to do the same job as HTML, but:

- is rendered directly (without actually being compiled down to x/html)
- is not just using a borrowed HTML-alike syntax (yes, I'm aware of SGML, which is widely known as the precursor of modern HTML)

The other thing is, I can see why HTML is popular: Its syntax is very easy to learn, no (overly awful) hidden black magic, it's a straight away markup language that does exactly what it says on the tin.

When people think of markup languages, they usually think of HTML. Markdown is compiled to HTML, so is every wiki syntax semi-language.  But there has got to be someone (or some company) who had a similar idea, and thusly tried to create a markup language that would fulfill similar, if not the same requirements.

I find it kind of hard to believe that there has never been any competitive markup language. Or has there really never been any?

Comment: HTML is compiled?  And hasn't the marketplace spoken?

Comment: @duffymo: I think he means languages that aren't converted/compiled *to* HTML. Not HTML itself being compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there’s [**Rich Text Format**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) which, although as far as I know never developed to be written by hand, nevertheless is human readable:

```
{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard
This is some {\b bold} text.\par
}
```

On the other hand, there’s [**PostScript**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) which, while also being a Turing-complete programming language, is used to mark up documents.

```
%!PS
/Courier             % name the desired font
20 selectfont        % choose the size in points and establish 
                     % the font as the current one
72 500 moveto        % position the current point at 
                     % coordinates 72, 500 (the origin is at the 
                     % lower-left corner of the page)
(Hello world!) show  % stroke the text in parentheses
showpage             % print all on the page
```

I’m sure there are more languages in the same vein. Looking for related articles on Wikipedia, [InterPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterPress) comes up, for instance.

Comment: I would argue RTF is more readable than PostScript, since PS is really a fullblown stackbased programming language that just so happens to be used to render documents. See http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:PostScript for the kind of things you can actually do in PostScript.

Comment: @nebukadnezzar Oh, RTF gets really funky once you start using different fonts (or font styles), colours and embedded images. At some point (which is reached pretty soon!) it’s essentially not manually editable any more.

Comment: yeah, I can see why that would be. It's not that much different in PS though... except that in PS you can define functions to shorten otherwise very "wordy" statements. :-)

Answer (score 3):

1) TeX

2) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_document_markup_languages

Comment: +1 even though, as far as I know, TeX is really always compiled to another format for displaying. But this is just because it’s practical, not for any particular technical reason.

Comment: OK, didn't know that, but "is rendered directly" is a very strange requirements, since every language is internally converted/compiled/transformed to some internal representation of the renderer.

Comment: The second link shows exactly what I addressed in the OP: that most of those are using a borrowed HTML syntax. Best example is probably GML: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Generalized_Markup_Language - it "looks" different, but if you look closely, you can guess what the processed result would probably look like...

Answer (score 1):

You might find http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/historical interesting.

There are loads of other document formats and markup languages but they don't really compete directly with HTML as such. Any potential competitor would have to overcome the fact that HTML (+CSS+JS) has become a sort of "universal language for everything" (i.e. it runs on everything, everywhere).